# Multiple slave agent in UVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am planning to implement multiple slave agents in my env and a single master agent.

Can anybody show me an example how to use this feature in UVM.And how do we start the item for a particular slave sequencer from the testcase.

Comment: Could you please add some more context to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty typical. Without details, the general outline is:

- In build_phase:

  - Create and configure the agents just as you have described.
  - The masters and slaves will be configured as active.

A slave agent is typically a reactive agent that responds to stimulus from the DUT so in that case, sequence items in the slave driver will be initiated by the DUT so they aren't under direct testcase control.